# Yii2 Relations to get a field using two foreign keys

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-model

I have issues to get a field from a table using two foreign keys.

Explained the relations of the use tables below.

- User table **hasMany** Companies(company_id).
- Comapny table has company_id.
- Facilities **hasOne** Company_id(Based on the user instance).
- Area **hasMany** Facilites(facility_id).

The logged on user will have areas related to facilities_id which in turn is related to company_id.

I now have a

- Productlines **hasMany** Products(product_id).

The user should display products related to the areas.

- Productlines **hasMany** Areas(area_id).
- Product lines has a field called internal_code.

Product model has relation with productlines on the basis of products_id.

I want to display this internal code on the basis of product_id which belongs to the specific areas.

My code as of now which is not working :

**In my product Model.**

```
    public function getFacility()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Facility::className(),['facility_id' => 'facility_id'])->viaTable('sim_users',['company_id'=> Yii::$app->user->identity->company_id]);
}

 public function getArea()
{

    return $this->hasMany(Area::className(),['area_id'=>'area_id'])->viaTable('sim_facility',['facility_id'=> 'facility_id' ]);
}

public function getProductlines()
{

    return $this->hasMany(Productlines::className(), ['product_id' => 'product_id'])->viaTable('sim_productlines',['product_id' => 'product_id']);
}
```

In my view file:

```
  [
        'label' => 'Internal Code',
        'format' => 'raw',

        'value' => function ($data) {
            foreach ($data->productlines as $intCode)
           return $intCode->internal_code;
        }
```

I don't understand how to link these relations. Looking for help. Thanks

List of Tables:

- Users (primaryKey - users_id, foreign_key- comapny_id)
- Company(primaryKey - company_id)
- Facility(primaryKey - facility_id, foreignKey- company_id)
- Areas(primaryKey - area_id, foreignKey- facility_id)
- Productlines(primaryKey - productlines_id, foreignKey - product_id and area_id)
- Product (primaryKey - product_id).

**My expected result:**

[image]

In the above table you can see area_id 47 has two product_id's (1 and 3). and the internal code for them is different. I want them to return both the internal codes as of now I can get only one internal code.

Comment: It is not clear what entities do you have and how they are linked. Could you provide complete list of tables with primary keys and foreign keys (just names will be enough)? And show please an example of expected result

Comment: @MaximKorshunov I have added the table names and relations..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have following hierarchy

- Company **hasMany** Users
- Company **hasMany** Facilities
- Facility **hasMany**  Areas
- Area **hasMany** ProductLines
- Product **hasMany** ProductLines

Products are linked to Areas as **manyToMany** **via** `productLines` relation

You can use following code for your AR classes (but You should fix the names, because I used a singular form for classes and table names):

```
public class User extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getCompany()
    {  
        retrun $this->hasOne(Company::className(), ['company_id' => 'company_id']);
    }
}

public class Company extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getUsers()
    {  
        retrun $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['company_id' => 'company_id']);
    }    

    public function getFacilities()
    {  
        retrun $this->hasMany(Facility::className(), ['company_id' => 'company_id']);
    }    
}

public class Facility extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getCompany()
    {  
        retrun $this->hasOne(Company::className(), ['company_id' => 'company_id']);
    }

    public function getAreas()
    {  
        retrun $this->hasMany(Area::className(), ['facility_id' => 'facility_id']);
    }    
}

public class Area extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getFacility()
    {  
        retrun $this->hasOne(Facility::className(), ['facility_id' => 'facility_id']);
    }

    public function getProductLines()
    {  
        retrun $this->hasMany(ProductLine::className(), ['area_id' => 'area_id']);
    }    

    public function getProducts()
    {  
        retrun $this->hasMany(Product::className(), ['product_id' => 'product_id'])
            ->via('productLines');
    }    
}

/**
 * @property $internal_code
 */
public class ProductLine extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getArea()
    {  
        retrun $this->hasOne(Area::className(), ['area_id' => 'area_id']);
    }

    public function getProducts()
    {  
        retrun $this->hasMany(Product::className(), ['product_id' => 'product_id']);
    }
}

public class Product extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getProductLines()
    {  
        retrun $this->hasMany(ProductLine::className(), ['product_id' => 'product_id']);
    }       

    public function getAreas()
    {  
        retrun $this->hasMany(Area::className(), ['area_id' => 'area_id'])
            ->via('productLines');
    }    

    public function getFacilites()
    {  
        retrun $this->hasMany(Facility::className(), ['facility_id' => 'facility_id'])
            ->via('areas');
    }
}
```

to get all internal codes for given product:

```
$productLines = $product->productLines;

$internalCodesAsArray = array_map(function(ProductLine $productLine) {
    return $productLine->internal_code;
}, $productLines);

$internalCodesAsString = join(', ', $internalCodesAsArray);
```

to get all internal codes for given area:

```
$productLines = $product->productLines;

$internalCodesAsArray = array_map(function(ProductLine $productLine) {
    return $productLine->internal_code;
}, $productLines);

$internalCodesAsString = join(', ', $internalCodesAsArray);
```

The same if you want to list products for given area -- use `$area->products` relation. If you want to get products count for given area, then call `$area->getProducts()->count();`

**To get internal codes of product for specific area** add following function into Product class:

```
public function getInternalCodes(Area $area = null)
{
    $query = $this->getProductLines();
    if (!empty($area)) {
        $query->where(['area_id' => $area->area_id]);
    }
    return array_map(function (ProductLine $productLine) {
        return $productLine->internal_code;
    }, $query->all());
}
```

And use it in your controller as `$currentProduct->getInternalCodes($currentArea)`

Do not add custom filters into functions that are define relations. If you want to get list of Facilities for given Product and filter them by company of current user  then better implement it as additional function:

```
public class Product 
{
    ...

    public function getFacilitiesByCompany(Company $company)
    {
        return $product->getFacilities()
            ->where(['company_id' => $company->company_id]);
    }
}
```

and use it as follows

```
$product->getFacilitiesByCompany(Yii::$app->user->identity->company)->all();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @MohanPrasad  Then probably i didn't get your question.

Comment: all your relations are perfectly intact.. It is just the view page code to get internal code..I have different areas. Based on that areas I get the products in my products page. different areas can have same products. Here same products have different internal codes. I want to display right internal code according to the areas.

Comment: @MohanPrasad I see. The answer updated: added example function for getting internal codes of a product in specified area